# How can I make a picture taller on smaller screens?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a picture taller the smaller the screen gets.

I currently have the following code:

```
<picture style="opacity:0.4">
    <source 
        type="image/webp" 
        sizes="width:100% height:10%" 
        srcset="images/background-image-200.webp 3840w 200h">
    <img 
        src="images/background-image-200.jpg" 3840w 200h
        sizes="width:100% height:10%">
</picture>
```

`height:10%` does exactly the opposite thing. It makes the image smaller on a smaller screen. What do I need to do to make it larger instead?

Comment: `height:10%` doesn't really make it smaller on smaller screen. Your image will always have a height of 10% of your screen. So yes, logically the image will look smaller on the small screen. To really change the image size according to screen size you will have to use css [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: @johannchopin Ok, maybe I've asked that in a wrong way. I don't actually want to change the image size. I just want to fill more of the screen with the image the smaller the screen gets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [media query](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp). Here is some example

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%; /* default height */
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .container {
    height: 20% /* this one will make your element taller on smaller device */
  }
}
```